# Почему не выполняется  if ?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s[] = new String[5];

    System.out.println("Введите числа");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        s[i] = sc.next();
    }

    Object obj = s;

        if(obj instanceof Integer)
        {
            int num[] = new int[5];
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                num[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
            }

            int aver = fun(num);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(aver);
        }

        if(obj instanceof Double)
        {
            double num[] = new double[5];
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                num[i] = Double.parseDouble(s[i]);
            }

            double aver = fun(num);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(aver);
        }
     sc.close();
}
}
```

Comment: А какого, по-вашему, типа `s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы сравниваете массив строк с числом.